# Having trouble removing callback from checkboxes

Tags: jquery

When a user gets to step 5 of my jQuery app, the code runs this:

```
buildStep5.find('input:checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {...
```

When the user goes back to step 4, I run this:

```
buildStep5.find('input:checkbox').empty();
```

I read in the jQuery documentation about remove() and empty() but I don't know how to make them work in this situation.  The result I get is when a user backs up to step 4 and then goes to step 5 the callback on the checkboxes runs twice for every one onChange event.  If anyone could help I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using `.off()` when you go back:

```
buildStep5.find('input:checkbox').off('change');
```

That way you'll remove the event handlers attached to your `change` event on step 5.

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't heard about that command.  It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on(), event 5 in you case.

Have a look :
[JQuery off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)